# How can I create Entities with OnetoMany and ManytoOne relationship?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, annotations

I have created two class namely Question.class and Option.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="QUESTION")
public class Question {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="QID")
private String QID;

@Column(name="CCODE")
private String ccode;

@Column(name="CPCODE")
private String cpcode;

@Column(name="QUES_TYPE")
private String qtype;


@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "QUES_ID", referencedColumnName="QID")
@IndexColumn(name="idx")
private List<Options> Opt;  
}
```

and Options class is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="OPTIONS")
public class Options {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="OPTION_ID")
private String opid;

@Column(name="OPTION_TYPE")
private String optype;


@Column(name="OPTIONS")
private String optn;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="QUES_ID")
private Question ques;
}
```

and I wrote a simple main class to insert datas

```
public void insertRow()
{
    Session s=getlSession(); 
      Transaction tx=s.beginTransaction();
 Question q=new Question("mah1", "cp1","text");
    Options op=new Options("text","b");
    op.setQues(q);
    s.save(q);
    s.save(op);

      tx.commit();
      s.close();
}

public static void main(String args[]){

    Test t=new Test();
    t.insertRow();


}
```

Now I am receiving this error in my console..

```
Hibernate: insert into QUESTION (CCODE, CPCODE, QUES_TYPE) values (?, ?, ?)
Dec 18, 2013 3:29:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
Dec 18, 2013 3:29:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Table 'testing.QUESTION' doesn't exist
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not   execute statement at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.    java:82)
```

If I took out the relationship between 2 entities and execute the program,it works fine and creates a table in my testing database. But while I using this relationship,its not working.

Comment: have you pointed to the right database?.if so then check for table existence..

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: Table 'testing.QUESTION' doesn't exist

-> You have to create the QUESTION table.